# Curve image on scroll

Tags: javascript

I was looking at a website [Firstborn website](https://www.firstborn.com/) and it's not the first time I've seen this effect, i wonder how it works. 
When you scroll down the page, you can see the images "curve" on top and bottom. I know I'm supposed to present some code, but I don't have any clue on how to create this type of curve on scroll effect!

Does anyone have ideas about how to make this effect is javascript? (Not the glitch, only the curvy image)?

Comment: They do it with WebGL.

Comment: Yes i've seen they used Three.js. So i have 2 questions : 1- Is there a workaround using Javascript only? / 2- How can you create this using Three.js ?